# Servidor de autenticação separado da aplicação

Tags: arquitetura-de-software

Tenho um cliente que vai desenvolver duas aplicações de sua empresa, ou seja, dois serviços oferecidos por sua empresa, e planos para outros projetos, e versões mobile dos mesmos.

Pois bem, por questões de modularização do projeto e facilidade de desenvolvimento de futuras aplicações, abstraimos todo o processo de autenticação das aplicações para um serviço único de autenticação/login.

Como fazer que toda a interação do usuário com sua conta, login, logout, atualização de dados, se dê em um único local, em um servidor e banco de dados à parte, deixando o servidor de cada aplicação livre e ocupado apenas com o que realmente lhe interessa?

A arquitetura que iremos utilizar é compartilhar um servidor de memcached como session handler das aplicações e do servidor de autenticação, os servidores estarão na mesma VPC na AWS

Comment: Oi, Thiago, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Editei sua pergunta para tirar coisas não relacionadas com o problema em foco. A pergunta já tem 1 voto para fechamento, vale a pena conferir a [help/on-topic] e o guia [ask] para esclarecer o problema um pouco mais.

Comment: O ambiente é Windows? Se for, utilizem AD e pronto, não precisam mais se preocupar com isso.

Comment: Você pode dar uma olha no [OpenId](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID). Mas qual tecnologia você vai utilizar? Qual framework? Talvez eu possa ajudar mais.

Comment: Eu acho que, hoje em dia, esse tipo de autenticação nem se faz mais. Todo mundo loga com Google OAuth, Facebutts, OpenID...

Comment: Ambiente Linux, PHP e Zend Framework 2. Mesmo com Login Social você precisa processar em algum momento. O Login social é apenas uma facilidade ao usuário, mas terás de programar igual.

Comment: Mais simples que compartilhar um memcached de sessão?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma das maneiras de simplificar é o seu servidor de aplicação usar algo parecido com o seguinte fluxo:

- A aplicação gera um *hash* e direciona o usuário para o servidor de *login* com esse parâmetro e mais um *token* se identificando;
- o servidor de *login* solicita e verifica as credenciais do usuário;
- caso o usuário cancele ou as credenciais não se confirmem após N vezes, o servidor de *login* devolve o usuário para a aplicação, sem confirmar o *login*, OU
- ao confirmar as credenciais, o servidor de *login* redireciona o usuário de volta para a aplicação, com o ID do usuário e um *hash* assinado por um valor comum armazenado pelas partes envolvidas.

Dá pra se fazer isto de uma maneira relativamente simples, sem se preocupar com OAuth e outros protocolos mal documentados e complexos demais para a necessidade específica.

Vantagens desta solução:

- Portátil - cada parte da aplicação pode ser dividida em diversas máquinas diferentes;
- pouco código necessário;
- funciona pra uma, duas ou duzentas aplicações, quantas forem necessárias;
- escalável, pois não depende de onde cada parte do sistema está rodando;
- simples de gerenciar, pois a única informação compartilhada entre as partes é o usuário autenticado, pelo retorno de um ID e assinatura válidos.

**Considerações importantes**

Este é um **esboço** geral, que faz sentido num ambiente não sujeito a ataques externos, ou a informações extremamente visadas (não que a solução não seja boa, mas ela só é tão boa quanto o seu cuidado de planejar os detalhes). Você é que tem que avaliar o grau de segurança necessário para a sua aplicação e decidir se vai simplificar ou utilizar alguma solução robusta. O difícil é separar as soluções robustas com motivo das apenas complicadas.

A explicação foi bem simplificada, apenas para dar uma visão geral. Cada etapa tem que ser devidamente cuidada, e você deve usar uma conexão segura e ter um *token* separado para cada aplicação cliente. Se a conexão não for segura, é necessário um passo a mais para obter um "contra *token*" do servidor.

Comment: Certo. E sempre que eu precisar confirmar as credenciais, sempre o mesmo processo né? E a sessão fica á cargo de cada aplicação?

Comment: A idéia é essa, isolar completamente os processos. Assim, você tem a vantagem da centralização do login, mas evita efeitos colaterais. Depois é claro que você pode incrementar o sistema, mas a vantagem é que fica tudo isolado. Mais interessante ainda é que se a pessoa salvar as credenciais na aplicação de login, ou se já tiver logado uma vez, quem vai cuidar disso é a a sessão do sistema de login apenas. Na hora que a segunda aplicação chamar, o redirecionamento já vai e volta de maneira transparente para o usuário.

Comment: Certo. E fica mais fácil de escalar, principalmente o memcached.

Comment: Como é feito esse redirecionamento de volta pra aplicação? Em outras palavras, ao fazer o redirect do servidor de login pro servidor da aplicação, onde armazenar o hash? Na própria URL? Minha preocupação é como manter esse hash seguro contra *replay attacks* ou similares (embora pensando aqui, imagino que isso pode ser mitigado usando um hash de curta validade...).

Comment: @mgibsonbr não é curta duração, é uso único. A aplicação cliente redireciona o user para autenticador/?hash=11dj1F31a268, por exemplo. O autenticador ao fazer um login com sucesso redireciona o user para cliente/?hash=hhDabG76GD&outrosparametros=outrosdados (que é o hash "assinado" por um secret que não é transitado pela web). Nesses outros dados, vc poe o que quiser (o user ID ou  outros dados pertinentes, que podem ser "hasheados" com o secret das 2 partes se desejar).

Comment: Eu peguei a ideia geral e achei muito interessante, mas ainda estou quebrando a cabeça pra entender como se implementa isso. Tipo, se é uso único então é preciso um meio de invalidá-lo, não? Da mesma forma, e se por alguma razão o hash assinado não for usado imediatamente? Digamos que o browser travou nesse momento e o usuário desistiu, e outro tomou o lugar dele (meu cenário é o lab. de informática de uma escola). Se o token ainda estiver lá, no histórico do navegador (possível, já que ele consta na URL) o próximo usuário pode abrir o browser e se encontrar autenticado como o primeiro...

Comment: De todo modo, eu não espero que você responda a isso, pois se formos entrar em todos esses detalhes a resposta ficará por demais extensa... O importante é que a ideia geral é boa, e com alguns cuidados pontuais pode ser uma solução excelente. Eu só discordo quando você fala em "protocolos (...) complexos demais para a necessidade específica", pois segurança **é** uma coisa complexa, e se esses protocolos fazem "malabarismos" que pra nós podem parecer estranhos, provavelmente é porque existe uma boa razão pros mesmos existirem! ;)

Comment: @mgibsonbr boa parte é complexa com motivo, mas outras partes são mal-feitas e mal documentadas. OAuth 2.0 por exemplo é complexo para uso em qq coisa. Inclusive eu uso para fazer Single Sign On com contas do google onde minha aplicação é o controlador das credenciais. Eu que tive que fazer malabarismos, isso sim, para contornar lacunas do protocolo (e não é falta de conhecimento, são problemas conhecidos por "academicismo excessivo", diferente de coisa que tem razão técnica de ser). Para não ficar o chat aqui, depois deleto este comment, e detalho melhor quando surgir ocasião mais oportuna.

Answer (score 2):

Considere utilizar o [CAS Central Authentication Service](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Home)

Basicamente, o CAS é uma aplicação em Java para a qual você delega o serviço de autenticação. Ela se integra, por exemplo, com o Active Directory, permitindo, assim, que o usuário utilize a mesma senha do AD para as aplicações WEB (algo interessante no caso de aplicações corporativas).

Utilizo o CAS com sucesso em uma aplicação desenvolvida em Grails (framework  Java web, baseado em Spring, Hibernate, etc).

O CAS roda em um servidor distinto das aplicações. Assim, qualquer aplicação que necessite de autenticação, nós delegamos a mesma para essa instância do CAS.

Você pode configurar para a autenticação acontecer com um banco de dados, via JDBC.

O CAS é nome do protocolo cujo a aplicação tem o mesmo nome. Ele é single sign-on, o que significa que após ter feito o logon em uma aplicação, as outras que forem abertas dentro da mesma sessão do browser compartilharão suas credenciais, não solicitando novamente usuário e senha.

Veja na página do CAS que existem clientes em Java, PHP, .NET, etc.