# Como fazer uma autenticação de login externo?

Tags: php, segurança, autenticação

Estou precisando desenvolver um sistema para ser usado pelo usuário.
O usuário estará cadastrado em outro sistema, onde teremos o cadastro, planos contratados e controle financeiro do mesmo...

A ideia é que quando o usuário tente logar no seu sistema, ao invés de ele autenticar dentro do banco de dados as informações do usuário, ele vá para o sistema "mestre", autentique o usuário e forneça as informações do plano dele...

Então a partir daí o usuário recebe a confirmação de autenticação do sistema "mestre" e pode usar o seu sistema...

Minha duvida é em como faço isso de forma segura? não quero expor informações do usuário e principalmente, não quero expor o sistema "mestre" que terá dados muito importantes dentro dele...

Comment: Eu estou nesse exato momento passando pelo mesmo problema, e uma boa resposta me ajudaria bastante! Mas se quiser que eu compartilhe as estratégias que venho delineando para isso - e os prós e contras que já identifiquei - posso fazer isso em breve. Além disso, gostaria que esclarecesse o seguinte: 1) ambos os sistemas estão sob controle da mesma entidade (ex.: sua empresa) ou não? Em outras palavras, o sistema A considera o sistema B "confiável" e vice-versa? 2) É importante para você que ao autenticar no sistema A o usuário esteja automaticamente autenticado no sistema B ou não?

Comment: @mgibsonbr os 2 sistemas vão ser da minha empresa, o usuário do sistema A não terá acesso a nada do sistema B, porém, a autenticação deve ser feita usando as informações que estarão contidas no sistema B. O uso disso é permitir que eu tenha a liberdade de criar N usuário para o sistema A, controlar seus pacotes entre outras coisas de forma centralizada a automatizada, sem correr riscos de que uma invasão ou algo do tipo no sistema A afete o sistema B que tentaremos deixar o mais "invisível" possível...

Comment: @mgibsonbr se quiser, pode ter a liberdade de editar a minha pergunta para informar os pros e contras entre outras informações que já tenha identificado na sua análise(caso os comentários sejam muito curtos para isso) acredito que temos um longo caminho pela frente

Comment: Você já chegou a considerar a ideia de utilizar o `OpenId` para realizar este processo?? [Site OpenId](http://openid.net/) [PHP OpenId](https://bitbucket.org/PEOFIAMP/phpoidc) É uma ideia interessante. Claro que tudo depende da arquitetura do seu sistema, e da necessidade. Mas fica a dica. Logando em um sistema, ao acessar outro ele automaticamente faz o login do usuário.

Comment: Valeu, mas isso não será necessário: pretendo postar como resposta. Seu caso é mais simples que o meu, onde embora um dos sistemas seja "mestre" ele também recebe logins diretamente. E um requisito do meu cliente - que por questões de segurança agora está sendo revisto - é que fosse feito o "login único", i.e. ao se autenticar em um serviço o usuário deveria automaticamente estar autenticado no outro. Ou seja, é um pouquinho mais complicado... :P

Comment: O OpenID (e OAuth2) são interessantes sim, mas no caso em que ambos os sistemas recebem login diretamente. No caso do AP, o sistema "mestre" não está diretamente acessível ao usuário, apenas indiretamente através do sistema "escravo". Assim, embora a sugestão seja boa, não creio que se aplique aqui...

Comment: @mgibsonbr Haaaaaa ta.. Se o sistema mestre não é visível, a aplicabilidade do OpenId não é valida.. Agora entendi.

Comment: Creio que podes implementar isso como um webservice no sistema B (são seguros e o utilizador nem se apercebe que está a fazer a autenticação noutro sistema)
http://php.net/manual/en/refs.webservice.php

Comment: O caso do @mgibsonbr `ao se autenticar em um serviço o usuário deveria automaticamente estar autenticado no outro` me lembrou os sites do Google, i.e. quando tu loga no Youtube, automaticamente já está logado no Google+... Enfim, só espiculando mesmo. :P

Comment: Dê uma espiada nessa: **[Servidor de autenticação separado da aplicação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32413/)**

Comment: @RodrigoBorth, creio que o que você precisa pode ser visto nessa resposta que acabei de postar há pouco tempo: [CAS](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32413/servidor-de-autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-separado-da-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o/34096#34096)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Um login "indireto" não é muito diferente de um login "direto". O usuário apresenta suas credenciais para o sistema A, o sistema A apresenta essas mesmas credenciais para o sistema B, que por sua vez responde com um "ok" ou não. As diferenças são as seguintes:

- É importante que o sistema A em si se autentique com o sistema B (de modo que o B saiba que está se comunicando de fato com o A). A forma de fazer isso vai depender da sua arquitetura, mas um meio comum e seguro é usar uma comunicação SSL/TLS entre os servidores, onde o A se autentica através de um "certificado no lado cliente" (*client certificate*).

  Não tenho experiência com PHP, mas [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/457874/520779) sugere o uso de `curl` para a comunicação servidor-servidor. [Esse post](http://www.binarytides.com/use-clientside-ssl-certificate-curl-php/) me parece dar uma visão geral do processo.
- Uma vez autenticado os servidores, A pode enviar as credenciais recebidas do usuário a B normalmente. Entretanto, como isso só é feito uma vez (no login), é necessário que um token de sessão seja usado para manter o usuário autenticado. Onde gerenciar esse token?

  A princípio, eu diria que essa é uma responsabilidade do servidor A - gerenciar toda a comunicação cliente-servidor, incluindo a decisão de manter o usuário logado por muito tempo, expirar a sessão após X minutos, deslogar ou não ao fechar o browser, etc. Ao servidor B não interessa a situação do usuário, se o servidor confiável A pediu informações de um usuário a B, ele deve simplesmente entregar! Não faz muito sentido o servidor B (*back end*) assumir pra si responsabilidades que seriam do servidor A (*front end*)...

  O que pode ocorrer de errado, no entanto, é alguma vulnerabilidade no servidor A levá-lo a fazer requisições incorretas ao servidor B. Se Mallory roubou a conta de Alice e se apresentou a A como Alice, A vai entregar de volta as informações pessoais de Alice, e não tem nada que B possa fazer a respeito. O que você pode fazer é tentar evitar resultados "catastróficos", tipo um SQL Injection em A faz com que ele mande a B uma requisição para obter dados de vários usuários ao mesmo tempo. Para se prevenir disso, B deve tratar A como se fosse um cliente comum - tomando as mesmas providências para sanitizar as entradas passadas por A que tomaria em relação a um cliente externo, não confiável.

  Ou seja, embora B a princípio confie em A, ele não "confia confia" - de modo que a validação adicional acrescenta à "defesa em profundidade".

Comment: é um Ótimo caminho para começar, se pensar bem, tenho que fazer o mesmo tratamento nos 2 servidores, uma vez que se por ventura tiver um ataque em A que faça ele disparar requisições para B, então tenho um problema em A e B, vou tentar sanitizar as fraquezas dessa comunicação nos dois lados... hackers fazem até milagre pra invadir um sistema :/

Comment: @RodrigoBorth além utilizar além do ssl entre os servidores, aconselho a informação ser criptografada também com blowfilsh ou algo parecido, dando duas camadas de criptografia. Você também pode utilizar mecanismos de heartbeat para saber se a comunicação entre o sistema A e B está "viva". As formas são inúmeras de proteção, para ser bem sincero, só de você não confiar em nada que parte do cliente e que não cometa erros bobos dificilmente terá alguma brecha em seu codigo

Comment: @brhvitor6 Que benefícios uma segunda camada de criptografia traria? Lembre-se que não adianta nada ter confidencialidade sem autenticidade [e integridade] - se o SSL falhar, você não sabe *com quem* está se comunicando, então não adianta nada a comunicação ser confidencial se "na outra ponta" está o atacante... Eu até vejo *alguma* vantagem se ambos os servidores compartilharem uma chave simétrica por exemplo, mas ainda abre espaço pra vários tipos de ataque (como *replays*). Na minha opinião é *overkill*, mas não sou especialista em segurança, pode ter algo que eu não sei a respeito.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Entre o cliente e o servidor A nenhuma, mas entre o servidor A e B seria interessante ter mais uma camada aplicada aos dados do cliente, assim o servidor A pode não ter "certeza" se esta "falando" com o servidor B mas os dados (por ex: login e senha) serão um bloco de criptografia, dificultando o acesso as informações. Sobre as caves simetricas, não sei se trariam grandes beneficios.. mas [diffie-hellman](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie-Hellman) está ai pra isso.. rs

Comment: @brhvitor6 Eu já penso exatamente o contrário: DH seria inútil por si só uma vez que "permite que duas partes que *não possuem conhecimento a priori de cada uma* compartilhar uma chave secreta...". De que adianta se comunicar de forma segura com o atacante? Já uma chave simétrica **previamente estabelecida** (ex.: instalada manualmente nos dois servidores) teria exatamente o efeito que você falou: 'A pode não ter "certeza" se esta "falando" com o servidor B mas os dados serão um bloco de criptografia'. De todo modo, IMHO ainda é *overkill*: há pouca razão para "desconfiar" do SSL.

Comment: Do jeito que vocês estão falando, até parece que o sistema do cara irá transportar números de cartões de créditos rs. Como ele não citou nos requisítos as necessidades, SSL está ótimo (até mais que o necessário), colocar mais uma "camada" de segurança seria desnecessário e só iria consumir mais recurso de máquina.

Comment: @wryel Exatamente o que eu penso! Só discordo que SSL seja "até mais que o necessário", creio que isso é indispensável quando se está tratando de dados privados. Só a comunicação servidor-servidor que *pode* ser desprotegida - se a mesma se der exclusivamente dentro da intranet da empresa (essa sim bem protegida).

Comment: Totalmente de acordo @mgibsonbr. Na verdade eu que não soube me expressar na resposta, o que eu queria dizer é que o SSL já tem um auto grau de segurança, até mais do que a aplicação dele precisa rs

Answer (score 2):

Se você não tiver como requisíto [Single sign On](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on), você pode usar um [Web Service](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) [SOAP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) (cujo objetivo é integrar) com [WS-Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) rodando em [https](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS).

- XML e WebServices ([Link para espeficicação](http://www.w3.org/2002/ws/)) são padrões documentandos e tem apoio da [W3C](http://www.w3.org/)
- Suas informações ficam protegidas pelo https e você pode definir políticas de quem pode ou não pode tentar fazer uma solicitação de logon
- Qualquer outra plataforma que dê suporte a XML pode reutilizar seu serviço (Android, Python, etc ...).
- A implementação de "como" e "onde" será validando o logon, fica à sua implementação, podendo ser em banco, LDAP ou ainda delegar para outro serviço.

Complementando o método do @Bacco na sua pergunta, tem um cliente meu que usa o modelo citado. O sistema de logon (extremamente simples) é java, porém, subsistemas existem em PHP, .NET, Ruby e Java. Na primeira chamada desses subsistemas, é passado por parametro o token (?token=ABCDEFGHIJK) e através de um componente de uso comum, esse token é validado  e conseguimos identificar o usuário logado por ele.

**Adicional**

[Cuidado com a otimização prematura](http://www.vidageek.net/performance-java/otimizacao-prematura/), e não tente reinventar a roda para padrões que já são evidentes que funcionam.

Answer (score 1):

O método de fazer o envio é o POST normal como você já esta acostuma, porém temos que pensar na segurança, veja os seguintes pontos:

1. Os servidores "sistema e 'mestre'" devem apenas se comunicar entre
   eles. Pessoal de infra pode te ajudar a configurar o firewall (ou
   eles mesmos podem fazer) para que esta comunicação entre sistemas
   não seja feito de outra fonte.
2. Utilização de comunicação SSL na comunicação entre os servidores (envio de POSTs entre eles deve estar criptografada);
3. Técnicas anti-XSS podem ser utilizadas no
   processo, mais informações aqui: [Cross-site scripting](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting);

Creio que seguindo esses 3 passos, já deixa seu sistema com segurança para realizar a autenticação necessária.

Sucesso!

Answer (score 0):

Esse sistema que o usuário tem que acessar "B" para ter acesso "A" pode ser feito com curl/php aonde você pode pegar o valores setados pelo usuário e manga para o sistema A, como  curl.